# Number formatting with react-intl

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-intl

I want to format a 'milage' number (in kilometers). So the value `{45000}` should be displayed like `45.000 km.`.

Is this possible to do?

**markup**

```
<p>{ intl.formatNumber(45000, mileageFormat) }</p>
```

**format options**

```
const mileageFormat: any = {
  style: '',
  // currency: 'km.',
  // currencyDisplay: 'dkk',
  // format: ''
}
```

I thought about using 'currency' property to show `km.` after the number, but ofcourse it's not working `km.` is not a currency!.

I also thought about using the `format` property, but can not find any documentation on how to use it... (https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/API#formatjs-internationalization-formatters)

Comment: checking the link you posted it seems that, as you said, km isn't a currency. Why don't you just format the value as you want instead?

Comment: Well, because I don't know how to do it! Do you?

Comment: yeah It can be done. I'll post an answer below

Comment: Thanks, but I want to know how to do it with react-intl.

Answer (score 3):

I used `intl.formatNumber` and it gave me what I needed:

`formatNumber(1000); // "1,000"`

I can then include the `km.` inside "defaultMessage" and let translators change that should they wish to.

Source: https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/API#number-formatting-apis

Answer (score -1):

This should format the number as you asked. I'm sure there are way better solutions but this should give you what you are looking for in the meantime.

```
formatNumber(val) {
    const value = val.toString();
    return `${value.substring(0, value.length - 3)}.${value.substring(value.length - 3, value.length)} km`;
}

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.formatNumber(45000)}</p>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: The thousand separator is hard coded in your solution, which is not a great experience for users of other locales.